# How to port updateMany from JS to scala using mongo driver?

Tags: mongodb, scala

Here is my JS mongo query:

```js
db.getCollection('my_collection')
.updateMany({},
[{ $set: { idempotencyKey: { $convert: { input: "$_id", to: "string" } } } }]
)
```

It works as expected, sets value of `$_id` field to `idempotencyKey`

I try to port it to scala code and it doesn't work

```scala
    val setDefaultIdempotencyKeyExpression =
      """{ $set: { idempotencyKey: { $convert: { input: "$_id", to: "string" } } } }""".stripMargin

    getCollection("my_collection").updateMany(
      Filters.not(Filters.exists("idempotencyKey")),
      Document(setDefaultIdempotencyKeyExpression)
    ).toFuture()
      .map(_.getModifiedCount)
```

I have no idea how to express JS query using scala DSL that is why i try to pass raw Json to Document.
It doesn't work as expected.
Code sets

```
{"$convert": {"input": "$_id", "to": "string"}}
```

as value to `idempotencyKey` field

I can't pass

```json
[{ $set: { idempotencyKey: { $convert: { input: "$_id", to: "string" } } }]
```

like in original JS query since Document doesn't accept array `[]`, it accepts only json object `{}`

What is the right spell to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I had to pass Seq of document, there is the overloaded method `updateMany` that accepts Seq[Document]

```scala
val setDefaultIdempotencyKeyExpression =
      """{ $set: { idempotencyKey: { $convert: { input: "$_id", to: "string" } } } }""".stripMargin

    getCollection("my_collection").updateMany(
      Filters.not(Filters.exists("idempotencyKey")),
      Seq(Document(setDefaultIdempotencyKeyExpression))
    ).toFuture()
      .map(_.getModifiedCount)
```

Don't fully follow idea behind, why Seq and single Document handled differently, but it works.